# Get a function name for a std::function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

I'm working on some 3-rd party code. The API implements a lot of functions that are indirectly managed using the `std::vector` of the `std::function`'s:

Here are the code excerpt:

```
class Delegate {
public:
...
// Invoke all functions in the delegate, passing the arguments provided (if any).
    void invoke(ArgT... args) {
        for (std::function<void(ArgT...)>& func : _functors) {
            func(args...);
        }
    }
...
// Adds a single function to the list.
    Delegate operator +=(Functor func) {
        add(std::move(func));
        return *this;
    }
...
};
```

My question is there a way to get the actual function name being passed to the `operator +=` (added to the container) or to the `invoke` (being effectively invoked/called)? (I'd like to make some actions when the actually added/called function name is for example "abc")
I've tried:

```
func.target_type().name() //1
func.target_type().raw_name() //2
func.target_type().hash_code() //3
```

but:

- #1 - returns just/only a function signature which is practically useless for me.
- #2, #3 returns some kind of hashes (#2 char-hash, #3 a number)  which are also useless for me.

Moreover I've noticed that for the functions with the same signatures the all three values are respectively the same!.

Comment: Probably not. For a start, not all functions even *have* a name. Think lambdas for example.

Comment: @Yeah, i know about the lambdas, but I know that all the functions  being added/invoke here DO HAVE the names!

Comment: Maybe you could try to use [`__FUNCTION__` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160).